# How can I run GPIO.wait_for_edge and an GPIO.add_event_detect on the same pin?

Tags: rpi.gpio, pi-zero

The code I'm trying to run looks something like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
sensor=4

def cb(r):#r is just accept the argument passed by add_event_detect
    c=GPIO.wait_for_edge(sensor,GPIO.RISING,timeout=300)
    if c!=sensor:
        print "do something if timeout happens before next signal"

GPIO.add_event_detect(sensor,GPIO.RISING,callback=cb)
```

When I run this I get **RuntimeError: Conflicting edge detection events already**. I've found this website https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=88951 which solves the case where two competing wait_for_edge cases are run simultaneously but:

I wasn't sure if this was would work for an event_detect and a wait_for_edge

I also wasn't sure if this would work with my specific hard/software specs. I'm running a Pi zero version 1.3 with what I assume is the latest version of Jesse that I downloaded last week from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/.

And furthermore I'm not the best at linux and don't want to damage my new PI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up side stepping this issue by using a thread and a class. Like so:

```
import time
import timeit.default_timer as tm
import threading.thread as TH
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
sensor=4

class wd(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.t=timeit.default_timer()
    def cb(self):
        ct==tm() #see import
        self.t=ct
        TH(self.waiter,args=(ct,)).start() #see import
    def waiter(self,ct):
        time.sleep(.3)
        if self.t==ct:
            print "do something if timeout happens before next signal"
w=wd()
GPIO.add_event_detect(sensor,GPIO.RISING,callback=w.cb)
```

The because this is threaded, the class has a chance to update self.t before it compares ct to self.t